# Passing a state variable as prop and it does not change on the first event

Tags: reactjs

I am passing a boolean managed by the state of my component to a Checkbox component but I am having issues with The checkbox responding to the changed state variable. The first time I click the checkbox that calls allRowCheck which I have verified, the check box does not change. When clicked a second time, it responds as needed and thereafter.

```
  render()
  {
    return(
      <div><Table  style = {{textAlign: 'right'}} data={this.state.testData2}
        rowStyle={(row, index) => {return { textAlign: 'right' };}}>
          <Table.Column
            header={<Form.Checkbox checked = {this.state.allRows}  onChange={() => this.allRowCheck()}/> }
            body={
              (data) => <Form.Checkbox checked = {data.get('checked')} onChange={() => this.onCheck(data)}/>
            }/>
            <Table.Column
              header={'Name'}
              body={(data) => data.get('scenarioName')} 
            />
            <Table.Column
              header={'Condition'}
              body={(data) => data.get('condition')}
            />
            <Table.Column
              header={'Notifications'}
              body={(data) => data.get('notifications')}/>
            <Table.Column
              header={'Owner'}
              body={(data) => data.get('owner')}/>
      </Table></div>
    )
  }
```

---

```
allRowCheck = () => {
    console.log('all row checks before> ', this.state.allRows);


    this.setState({

        testData2: this.state.testData2.map((data) => data.set('checked', !this.state.allRows)),

    })
    //twp set states for no reason..
    this.setState({
      allRows: !this.state.allRows
    }, () => {
      console.log('after> ', this.state.allRows)
    })

  }
```

Comment: What logs from `allRowCheck` method, do you see on console when you click first time?

Comment: all row checks before>  false
 after>  true